# Use lastInsertId() multiple times on different queries in transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I've been trying to find an answer but I don't think there is one that is specified to what I am trying to do. I will start with my sample of code

**file.php**

```
$q = "INSERT INTO ".PORTAL_DB.".resource_file (company__id, rf_category__id, title, file_name, description, path, upload_by, has_quiz)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, CONCAT(MAX(id)+1, '.', '$extension'), ?, ?, ?, ? FROM ".PORTAL_DB.".resource_file";
$stmt = $CONN->prepare($q);
$filename = 0;
$resource_file__id = 0;
if($stmt->execute(array($company__id, $rf_category__id, $title, $description, "assets/$uploadFolder/", USER, $has_quiz))){
    $filename = $CONN->lastInsertId();
    $resource_file__id = $filename;
}

if(!empty($quiz)){
    $passing_score = $quiz->passing_score;
    if(!is_numeric($passing_score) or ($passing_score < 0) or $passing_score > 100){
        $CONN->rollback();
        throw new Exception("Invalid passing score value for quiz, please fix");
    }
    $q = "INSERT INTO ".PORTAL_DB.".rf_quiz (resource_file__id, passing_score)
    VALUES(?, ?)";
    $stmt = $CONN->prepare($q);
    $rf_quiz__id = 0;
    $stmt->execute(array($resource_file__id, $passing_score));
    print_r($CONN->lastInsertId);
    exit;
    $question_ids = array();
    foreach($quiz as $qz){
        $question = $qz->question;
        //print_r($qz);
        $q = "INSERT INTO ".PORTAL_DB.".rf_quiz_question (rf_quiz__id, question)
        VALUES(?, ?)";
        $stmt = $CONN->prepare($q);
        if($stmt->execute(array($rf_quiz__id, $question))){
            array_push($question_ids, $CONN->lastInsertId);
        }
    }
    //print_r($question_ids);
    exit; // using this for testing only
}
```

**explanation**

The above code is called after `$CONN->beginTransaction()` so that I can manage errors easier. From what I understand you can call the stamtement `$CONN->lastInsertId()` multiple times without issue, however I can get the first id which is stored under the variable `$resource_fild__id` then when we go down to the `$rf_quiz__id` variable, even if the call is successful, I get nothing and it causes an error. I want to be able to do all of this in one transaction for the ease of the coding process and organization.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, or at least be able to tell me what I am doing wrong so that I can find a fast solution!

Thank you for all help in advance.

Comment: `$rf_quiz__id` is always 0. Is it ok? Maybe you forget about something like this: `$rf_quiz__id = $CONN->lastInsertId;` ?

Comment: @mnv If you look at the code after `$rf_quiz__id` I have a `print_r($CONN->lastInsertId());` then I placed an `exit;` call in the most recent edit. This is where it is showing nothing

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#107622): **Remember, if you use a transaction you should use lastInsertId BEFORE you commit
otherwise it will return 0**

Comment: @Barmar that can't be completely true though because at the top when i get `$filename` that gives a non-zero id value. All my uploaded files via that id are correct.

Comment: Where is your `$CONN->commit()`, BTW?

Comment: many more lines down in the code, for the sake of simplicity I put only the relevant code needed, the `$CONN->beginTransaction();` is not present either if you notice.

Comment: You said it's causing an error. What error are you getting?

Comment: I got the error `integrity something something, rf_quiz__id column can not be null`

Comment: `lastInsertId()` is a method, but you seem to use it as an attribute